# How to access windows shared folder from ubuntu without password?

Tags: networking, server, samba, shared-folders, sharing

I want to get my network between Desktop(win7) and laptop(Ubuntu) working. I hoped to get the windows-like network file browsing, but this don't work. When I go to network in Ubuntu, there is just "Windows share" icon and when I click it, I get "Failed to retrieve share list from server".

So I tried the connect to server option using the desktop name and then IP address and both are working, however I need to enter name and password every time. But this way I can access whole computer(desktop).

So what I want:

1. be able to see the desktop PC(win7) in network
2. be able to acces the folders I share on that computer

Now a few notes:

- I went to advanced sharing on the win7 PC and unchecked the password sharing option
- I also shared the folder on that PC and set up the permissions of the shared folder to "everyone"
- both PCs are in the same workgroup
- I have samba installed

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable firewall on windows, or if you don't want to disable it, set the network as home or work network.
In default firewall settings the shares and network discovery is blocked.